# How to make a bag of words using split method from a text file in python

Tags: python, tf-idf

I am trying to learn TFIDF. But I coudnt bag the words from file.

code:

```
docA = open("/home/user/Desktop/da/doca","r")
print(docA.read())
bowA = docA.split(" ")
```

error:

```
AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-06e07f9dd975> in <module>
----> 1 bowA = docA.split(" ")

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'`
Can anyone help me solve this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you meant this:

```py
docA = open("/home/user/Desktop/da/doca","r")
# print(docA.read())
bowA = docA.read().split(" ") # or just split() will do
docA.close()
```

When you call `read()` the read cursor reads the entire file, leaving the read-cursor at the end. So calling `read()` again will return empty string. Hence if you would like to print the content, you can assign the content to a variable, print it and use it as you wish:

```py
docA = open("/home/user/Desktop/da/doca","r")
data = docA.read()
print(data)
bowA = data.split()
docA.close()
```

Or simply

```py
with open("/home/user/Desktop/da/doca","r") as docA:
    data = docA.read()
print(data)
bowA = data.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the returned string instead of the file handle:

```
docA = open("/home/user/Desktop/da/doca","r")
document_string = docA.read()
bowA = document_string.split()
```

You can just call `split`, by default it splits on whitespace